# Why isn't the 3 pts function vanishing in the Ising model by Z_2 symmetry?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ising-model

The Ising model with vanishing external field possesses the $Z_2$ symmetry:

$$\sigma_i \rightarrow - \sigma_i$$

implying that the 1 pt function vanishes:

$$<\sigma_i> \;= 0$$

In the same way, shouldn't all the n point functions vanish for n odd?

But at its critical point, the 3 pt function obeys the following by conformal symmetry:

$$<\sigma_i\,\sigma_j\,\sigma_k> \;\propto \; \frac{1}{|i-j|^{\frac14}|k-j|^{\frac14}|k-i|^{\frac14}}$$

and so, except if the coefficient factor is zero doesn't vanish.

Where is the mistake in this reasoning?

Comment: At zero external field, $n$-point functions with $n$ odd always vanish (when there is a unique infinite-volume Gibbs state, which is the case at the critical point). That's actually trivial if you start from the measure with free (or periodic) boundary conditions in a finite box, since then $\langle \sigma_i \sigma_j \sigma_k\rangle = -\langle (-\sigma_i) (-\sigma_j) (-\sigma_k)\rangle = -\langle \sigma_i \sigma_j \sigma_k\rangle$, by symmetry.

Comment: Yes so it means to reconcile it with the expression given under the constraint of the conformal symmetry we need to have the coefficient factor ($C_{\sigma\sigma\sigma}$) is zero?

Comment: If your computation is correct, yes, that seems to be the conclusion.

Comment: Yes, $C_{\sigma\sigma\sigma}=0$ in the absence of a magnetic field. So it might be better to state it as $C_{\sigma\sigma\sigma}=\mathcal{O}(h)$, where $h$ is the magnetic coupling constant.

Comment: Yes, but if you have non zero magnetic field then we don't have conformal symmetry and we're not talking about the same structure constants, isn't it?